# Calculating capacitance and resistance for transformerless power supply

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, diodes, circuit-design, homework

Here is the circuit:
[image]
Zener diode is 6.2v, 1watt and R4 is the load so that
$$250\le R_4\le500$$
If ripple voltage of C2 is 2V, determine values of R3 and C2 such that a constant 6.2 voltage appears across R4.

**Note:** Values of other elements are fixed.

Using reactance of the C1, we find that current through the source is approximately 45.9mA. Also we have 
$$2mA \le I_z \le 161mA$$
$$12.4mA \le I_L \le 24.8mA$$

I don't know how to calculate R3 and peak voltage across C2 with that information. If we find them, then determining C2 is straightforward using ripple formula :

$$V_r = \frac{V_p}{2fRC}$$

With the help of simulation, I tested several values and R3=100Ohm, C2=1mF worked very well but don't know how to actually calculate them by hand.

Comment: R3 is too high. 50 Ohm load tries to draw more than 100mA. Even if zero current flows through the Zener, the voltage drop across that 1k resistor (R3) will be around 100V. So the circuit cannot work. PS-1: Capacitive power supply is a terrible choice for more than 20mA. PS-2: For 100mA current, the ballast capacitor could a few tens of microFarads.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I even tried R3=1 but it didn't work.

Comment: Try with C1 = 4u7 and R3 = 100R. C2 is too low for 100mA load current. Increase it to something like 100u. Additionally, V1's "amplitude" is 220V. Shouldn't it be 312V? Amplitude and RMS are different things.

Comment: @RohatKılıç You're right, I fixed that. Using the values that you have mentioned, ripple is high and voltage doesn't exceed 2.25V.

Comment: Read again carefully what I've written above. `C1 = 4u7, C2 = 100u`. But in your schematic, C2 = 4u7 and C1 is still 470n.

Comment: @RohatKılıç According to the question value of C1 is fixed and equals to 470n.

Comment: With C1=470n it's impossible to get 100mA output current! Calculate its reactance at f=50Hz and then the voltage drop across it at 100mA output current. You'll see what I'm trying to say. Say hello to the guy who prepared the question!

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thanks for your help. If the load resistance is 1K then we can choose R3 and C2 properly without altering C1, right?

Comment: Not that easy to answer. Take a look at [here](http://www.designercircuits.com/DesignNote1c.pdf). Also, google "transformerless capacitive power supply design".

Comment: @RohatKılıç That was really helpful. I've edited my question. Could you take a look, please?